# Why annotations written in Scala are not accessible at runtime?

Tags: scala, annotations, runtime

I have come across a statement in scalatest documentation:

```
It must be defined in Java instead of Scala so it will be accessible at runtime.
```

This is quite weird as I was under the impression that Scala annotation is stronger than its Java counterpart. Why this feature is missing? Is there a plan to add it back?

Comment: I dont think that Scala is in favour of annotations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609218/why-scala-people-dont-like-annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no known plan to have Scala support annotations retained at runtime (the issue has been known for a while but as [this page](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-32) says, it won't be fixed).

[Lukas Rytz](https://github.com/lrytz), a Scala committer, explained on [a post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-language/XWbSI1rKYns/6UDFhAzw4xoJ) on the `scala-language` mailing list:

> It's definitely non-trivial. Java annotations have specific
>   representation in bytecode [...],
>   which would require changes to Scala's bytecode generator.
>
> Also the language of java annotations is quite special, different from
>   the rest of the Java language [...], so one would need to define
>   how this can be represented in a Scala class.

Comment: Wow, I don't know its that complex, but I assume that all scala specialist know some Java & reflection so this won't be a big problem.